# Using grep to index out rows in r

Tags: regex, r, indexing

I am trying to filter out data by searching for a particular keyword in the comments. I'm working with the following:

```
  > resp4[c(12:15,155:165),]
      DstSource MinDist    A    B    C    TypeOth DEF
  17        PLG      10 0.80 0.10 0.10       <NA>   0
  18        OGT       0 0.70 0.10 0.20       COTE   0
  19        OGT      10 1.00 0.00 0.00       <NA>   0
  21        OGT       0 0.50 0.25 0.25       <NA>   0
  301       OGT       0 1.00 0.00 0.00       LAGU   0
  304       PLG       0 0.40 0.10 0.50 large gull   0
  306       OGT       0 0.90 0.10 0.00      terns   0
  309       OGT       0 0.80 0.20 0.00      terns   0
  311       OGT       0 0.70 0.30 0.00      terns   0
  312       OGT       0 1.00 0.00 0.00       LAGU   0
  314       OGT       0 1.00 0.00 0.00       LAGU   0
  315       OGT       0 0.50 0.50 0.00       LAGU   0
  316       OGT       0 1.00 0.00 0.00       LAGU   0
  317       OGT       0 1.00 0.00 0.00      terns   0
  319       PLG      10 0.95 0.05 0.00       <NA>   0
```

And I am trying to specifically remove rows where `TypeOth` either contains the phrase "tern" (and it appears both as singular and multiple, upper and lower case through the data frame) or matches the whole expression "COTE". I know that if I was looking specifically for these entries, I could use

```
 resp4 <- resp4[grep("tern|cote",resp4$TypeOth, ignore.case=T),]
```

Can someone point me towards how to index out the rows that my `grep` statement returns? Whenever I try to convert it to a logical command, it returns an empty object. For example, the following code does not work.

```
 resp4 <- resp4[!(grep("tern|cote",resp4$TypeOth, ignore.case=T)),]
```

Comment: You can use `grepl` (with an l) which returns a logical index and then just negate it with `!`. Also note that `grep` has an `invert` argument which you could also use (it is `FALSE` by default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options, among them:

```
resp4[grep("tern|cote",resp4$TypeOth, ignore.case = TRUE, invert = TRUE),]
```

Or

```
resp4[!grepl("tern|cote",resp4$TypeOth, ignore.case = TRUE),]
```

To name two of them.

Another one,

```
resp4[-grep("tern|cote",resp4$TypeOth, ignore.case = TRUE),]
```

works in this case but I wouldn't recommend. Why? Look what happens if no matches are found:

```
> resp4[-grep("XXXX",resp4$TypeOth, ignore.case = TRUE),] 
#[1] DstSource MinDist   A         B         C         TypeOth   DEF      
#<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)
```

The first two options are safer for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
resp4 <- resp4[-grep("tern|cote",resp4$TypeOth, ignore.case = TRUE),]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: `grep` won't work properly in case of no match. `grepl` is always preferred for such situations.